# How to crop before uploading with Cloudinary's own widget uploader?

Tags: angular, image, cloudinary

I'm working on an app which uses [Cloudinary's Upload Widget](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_widget) which helps me uploading images and crop them but I realised it doesn't actually crop the image before uploading, but it creates an "Area of interest" which is not what I'm looking for because if I only need a small area from an big image it uploads the whole image (using .

Is there a way? I looked into the docs but I couldn't find any clue.

```
this.widget = this.cloudinary.createUploadWidget({
      cloudName: "######",
      uploadPreset: "###",
      cropping: true,
      croppingCoordinatesMode: "custom",
      apiKey: "##########",
      uploadSignature: this.generateSignature.bind(this)
    }, (error, result) => {
      console.log(result)
      console.error(error)
    })
```

I actually need the widget to actually crop before uploading.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use incoming transformation which will be in your preset->Upload manipulations and set the crop to crop and gravity to custom. 
Also add cropping: true in the widget params and that should crop the selected part of the image and only the cropped image will be uploaded.

Comment: First of all, I really appreciate the quick response, I already set cropping to true. But I'll try set what you said in the preset settings and come back with the result.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much!